# Converter not getting called at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter, multibinding

I have user control with dependency property selected items(which is a collection of enum values)

```
public IEnumerable SelectedItems
{
    get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(IEnumerable),
      typeof(UserControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnChangeSelectedItems)
      {
          BindsTwoWayByDefault = true
      });


private static void OnChangeSelectedItems(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var uc = d as UserControl1;

    if (uc != null)
    {
        var oldObservable = e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        var newObservable = e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (oldObservable != null)
        {
            oldObservable.CollectionChanged -= uc.SelectedItemsContentChanged;
        }
        if (newObservable != null)
        {
            newObservable.CollectionChanged += uc.SelectedItemsContentChanged;
            uc.UpdateMultiSelectControl();

        }
    }

}

private void SelectedItemsContentChanged(object d, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateMultiSelectControl();
}
```

I have binded selectedItems dependency property with a checkbox in my user control using a converter

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <CheckBox x:Name="ChkBox" Margin="13 0 0 10"  Content="{Binding}" >
                    <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CheckBoxConverter}"  Mode="TwoWay" >
                            <Binding ElementName="ChkBox" Path="Content" />
                            <Binding  RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"  Path="DataContext.SelectedItems" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"  Mode="TwoWay"></Binding>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </CheckBox.IsChecked>

                </CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

and converter

```
public class CheckBoxConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
           object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values != null && values.Length > 1)
        {
            var content = values[0];
            var selected = values[1] as IList;

            if (selected != null && selected.Contains(content))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;

    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes,
           object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new[] { Binding.DoNothing, Binding.DoNothing };
    }
}
```

My problems is if I add values in Selected items at the time of construction the converter is getting called but if I add values on a button click ,its not getting called.Can anybody tell me the reason why its happening and how i can correct this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Convert` method of the converter only gets called when any of the properties that you bind to changes. You are binding to the `Content` property of the `CheckBox` and the `SelectedItems` property of the `UserControl`. Neither of these change when you add a new item to the collection.

Try to also bind to the `Count` property of the collection:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="ChkBox" Margin="13 0 0 10"  Content="{Binding}" >
    <CheckBox.IsChecked>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CheckBoxConverter}"  Mode="TwoWay" >
            <Binding ElementName="ChkBox" Path="Content" />
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" Path="SelectedItems"/>
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" Path="SelectedItems.Count"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
</CheckBox>
```